# Need explanation for maven error please

Tags: maven, maven-nar-plugin

http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2012/07/building-cc-applications-with-maven/comment-page-1/#comment-8196

I'm following the example above for the maven nar plugin, but I get the following error when I do a mvn package

“could not find artifact net.sf.antcontrib:cpptasks-parallel:jar:1.0-beta-5-parallel-1-SNAPSHOT” but I see the following folder tree and its contents in my ~/.m2/repository... What gives?

```
~
   .m2
      repository
         net
            sf
               antcontrib
                  cpptasks-parallel
                     1.0-beta-5-parallel-1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Are you sure you have Jar there? Or only Pom?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Unfortunately, neither `maven-nar-plugin` nor `cpptasks-parallel` are currently deployed to Central. So you need to `mvn install` them yourself (or better, `mvn deploy` them to your own Maven repository). You can find both projects [on GitHub](https://github.com/maven-nar).</s>

EDIT: `nar-maven-plugin` version 3.0.0 has been released, and is now [available from Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.maven-nar%7Cnar-maven-plugin%7C3.0.0%7Cmaven-plugin). Two notes:

1. The groupId and artifactId changed; the GAV is now:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
       <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. The `cpptasks-parallel` project has been merged into `nar-maven-plugin`, so no need to worry about that dependency anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.antcontrib</groupId>
 <artifactId>cpptasks-parallel</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-beta-5-parallel-1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.codeswarm</groupId>
 <artifactId>cpptasks-parallel</artifactId>
 <version>20121119</version>
</dependency>
```